# npm not installing jsdom in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, jsdom

Im building an app in node.js with jQuery, but when I try to execute, it says it couldnt find module `jsdom` so, even though I dont understand why installing jQuery didnt install this dependency, I run manually `npm install jsdom` and I get this error message:

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2)
>   install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of t he
>   component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere. 
>   [C:\Sites\myapp\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]

I tried the first option, but still didnt help. What am I (missing|doing wrong)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not the only one having issues with installing jsdom on windows. You could try these instructions:
http://www.steveworkman.com/node-js/2012/installing-jsdom-on-windows/

or use [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) which is easier to install on windows and does a similar job.

Comment: I have to actually install Visual Studio??? Outrageous. Na-ha. No way. I will have a look at Cheerio. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Dbugger To be fair, it works fine on linux/Mac because they generally have Python and a C++ compiler bundled with the OS install. For Windows, you need to obtain each yourself. Though, as noted in the [`node-gyp` docs](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation), the free Express edition of VS work fine.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `Cheerio`. It's easy to install and use.

Comment: thanks muchly for suggesting `Cheerio`, its working much faster, and so annoyed that I still jave `jsdom` existing in my archives